# Can't access Django site in production

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I can't access my Django website on production. It returns me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

EDIT : My error is :

```
File "/home/chuck/sitepro/site/sitepro/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
```

I use Nginx + Gunicorn + Supervisor in Ubuntu 16.04.

Here's my sitepro.conf (supervisor)

```
[program:sitepro]
command = /home/chuck/sitepro/bin/gunicorn sitepro.wsgi:application -w 4 -b :8002 --$
directory = /home/chuck/sitepro/site/sitepro
user = chuck
stdout_logfile = /home/chuck/sitepro/site/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stdout.log
stderr_logfile = /home/chuck/sitepro/site/logs/gunicorn/gunicorn_stderr.log
redirect_stderr = True
environment = PRODUCTION=1
```

And my Nginx configuration file :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;
    return 301 https://www.mywebsite.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mywebsite.com;
    root /home/chuck/sitepro/site;

    access_log /home/chuck/sitepro/site/logs/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /home/chuck/sitepro/site/logs/nginx/error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My root folder is in /home/chuck/sitepro/site/ and sitepro is my main application, containing Django default wsgi.py.

The port 8002 is open in ufw. Logs are empty.

Did I miss something ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you see any error in Nginx error log `/home/chuck/sitepro/site/logs/nginx/error.log` ?

Comment: No sorry the files are empty :/

Comment: Are your ports open on your nginx server? If you're not seeing anything in the nginx logs, that'd leave me to believe something is amiss just before the connection gets to nginx.

Comment: Can you ssh into the host and then curl localhost:8001? Actually, if your nginx logs are empty then the request isn't even getting that far and you're probably looking at a firewall issue.  Also have you tried both http and https requests?

Comment: My port is open. I just try to launch a gurnicon local command :
gunicorn wsgi.py:application --bind :8002
And I've got :

Comment: ImportError: Failed to find application, did you mean 'wsgi:application'?

Comment: But wsgi.py is in the directory.... :/

Comment: (sitepro) chuck@vps:~/sitepro/site/sitepro$ ls
admin.py  __init__.py  models.py    settings.py  urls.py   wsgi.py
forms.py  migrations   __pycache__  templates    views.py  wsgi.pyc

Comment: I tried this instead :

(sitepro) chuck@vps464339:~/sitepro/site$ gunicorn sitepro.wsgi:application --bind :8002

ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi

Maybe a "better" issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue : I made a "pip install django" and it's working now.
Thanks to all commentators for help !